# integral of difference of squares

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm familiar with the integral formula:

$\int \frac{1}{x^{2}-a^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\mid \frac{x-a}{x+a} \mid $

But if $a=0$ then you get:

$\int \frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=-\frac{1}{x}$

Is there any intuitive explanation for this?

Maybe one can show that the first formula approaches the second formula as $a$ approaches $0$?

Thanks

Comment: Well the first expression is not defined for $a = 0$, but certainly if you calculate the limit $a\to 0$ then both give same result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the limit $a\to 0$, then use the definition of differentiation for function $\ln|x|$:

$$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\ln|x-a|-\ln|x+a|}{-2a} =  \frac{1}{x}$$

And so you see both are equal as $a\to 0$. But the first formula is not valid for $a = 0$.